# How to test flash.message in a Grails webflow?

Tags: testing, grails, spring-webflow

I'm using webflows in Grails and I'm currently writing tests for it. Now, inside I've got something that throws an error so I set a message to the flash scope before redirecting:

```
...
if (some_condition) {
   flash.message = "my error message"
   return error()
}
...
```

Now, I know that when I'm going to display this in the GSP page, I access the flash message as

```
<g:if test="${message}">...
```

instead of the usual

```
<g:if test="${flash.message}">...
```

So anyway, I'm writing my test and I'm wondering how to test the content of the message? Usually, in normal actions in the controllers, I follow what's written in [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-5926) . However, since this is a webflow, I can't seem to find the message even if I check controller.flash.message / controller.params.message / controller.message . I've also tried looking at the flow scope...

Any ideas on how to see the message then? Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your example, you can access your `flash.message` as `controller.request.message` in your webflow test.  I did a lot of googling for this same exact issue and a lot of webflow documentations talk about it merging all scopes into the "view model".  But I also read somewhere that it merges the flash scope into the request scope for redirection.  That's what prompted me to try looking in the `controller.request` in my test case.